# POST request elasticsearch with no body

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not allowed request bodies. Post requests have to be done using just the url

Is it possible for me to use elasticsearch in this scenario?

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
POST host/doublepull/run?data='{"dsl":0,"fnl":0.75}'

POST host/doublepull/run?dsl=0&fnl=0.75

POST host/doublepull/run?'{"dsl":0,"fnl":0.75}'
```

but nothing appears to fit (always get IllegalArgumentException). Could not find any documentation on trying to use POST for it in this way

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not allowed to send anything in the request body. That's a pretty serious limitation

Comment: yeah it's kind of limited api (dota2 bot api) in some aspects.

I will probably just beg them to add in allowing request body :D